# Password Protect Ubuntu Idle/Sleep Wake-up

Tags: ubuntu, sleep

Can I password protect when Ubuntu wakes up from an idle or sleep, like you can in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Open *System > Preferences > Screensaver* and select the "Lock screen when screensaver is active" option. Next, run **gconf-editor**, navigate to */apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/use_screensaver_settings* and enable *use_screensaver_settings*.

Comment: This worked for me in v9 but not in v10. As a work-around, I created a shortcut to pm-suspend on my panel (for some reason, other suspend options still lock the screen - I think this is a bug).

Comment: This works for me in 9.04, and 10.04. Thanks